# Некорректный вывод информации Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Уже долгое время ломаю голову, но не могу добиться корректного вывода информации в программе. Объясню на примере: имеется фото формата png, больше заданного размера (размер задается на форме) и при этом название фото не соответствует названию папки (если включить чекбокс). По логике должно вывести 2(3) ошибки, а выводит только одну. Как добиться корректного вывода информации? То есть чтобы я нажал кнопку, а мне сразу вывело 2 ошибки, включил чекбокс - соответственно 3.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ScanDir(StartDir: string; Mask: string; List: TStrings);
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  dirname:string;
begin
  if Mask = '' then Mask := '*.*';
  StartDir := IncludeTrailingBackSlash(StartDir);
  if FindFirst(StartDir + Mask, faDirectory, SearchRec) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
    Application.ProcessMessages;
      if (SearchRec.Name = '..') or (SearchRec.Name = '.') then continue;
      if (SearchRec.attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
      begin
        ScanDir(StartDir + SearchRec.Name, Mask, List);
      end
      else
      begin
        if ((SearchRec.Size / 1024 / 1024) < maxS) and ((SearchRec.Size / 1024 / 1024) > minS) then
          if ExtractFileExt(StartDir + SearchRec.Name) = ext then
          begin
            if chk1.Checked then
            begin
              dirname := ExtractFileDir(StartDir + SearchRec.Name);
              Delete(dirname, 1, LastDelimiter('\', dirname));
              if dirname = Copy(SearchRec.Name,1,Pos('_',SearchRec.Name)-1) then
                List.Add(StartDir + SearchRec.Name)
              else
                List.Add('S' + StartDir + SearchRec.Name)
            end
            else
              List.Add(StartDir + SearchRec.Name)
          end
          else
            List.Add('S' + StartDir + SearchRec.Name)
        else
          List.Add('S' + StartDir + SearchRec.Name);
      end;
    until FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0;
    FindClose(SearchRec);
  end;
end;
```

Код в Button1:

```pascal
list := TStringList.Create;
  ScanDir(dir, '', list);
  for i := 0 to list.Count - 1 do
  begin
    try
      str := list.Strings[i];
      if (Copy(str, 1, 1) = 'S') then
      begin
        delete(str, 1, 1);
        lst1.Items.Add(str);
      end
    except
      lst1.Items.Add('Не получилось обработать: ' + str);
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Такая логика подходит?

```
bOK := True;
if Size за пределами then begin
   List.Add('S файл однако велИк ' + StartDir + SearchRec.Name);
   bOK := False;
end;
if bChkBoxChecked and ЧегоТоТамСПапкой then begin
   List.Add('S папка плоховата' + StartDir + SearchRec.Name);
   bOK := False;
end;
if Ext не то then begin
   List.Add('S расширение подкачало ' + StartDir + SearchRec.Name);
   bOK := False;
end;
if bOK then
    List.Add(StartDir + SearchRec.Name);
```

P.S. Не стоит проверять `if chk1.Checked` в цикле. Нужно установить переменную и сверяться с ней.